# Marriage certificate from church for UK Visa

Tags: united-kingdom

I am having my wife name endorsed in passport and my name in wife passport. We are having marriage certificate from church. Can we apply the ICT short term staff partner with that for my wife from India?

I am currently in the UK.

Comment: Where did you get married - India or the UK?

Comment: I got married in India.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as unclear, absent additional information on how an intra-company transfer relates to marriage/spouse, and visa for whom (as dependent?)